# Can a quantum state with infinite variance of photon number be found in nature or artificially created?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose we have a quantum state $\rho$ and let's denote the photon number operator $\hat{n}=\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$ where $\hat{a}$ is the annihilation operator.  Let mean photon number $\bar{n}=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\hat{n})<\infty$ obviously be finite.  Can $\rho$ have infinite photon number *variance*, which we define as follows:

$$\operatorname{Var}(\rho)=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}\hat{a})-\bar{n}^2$$

I ask this because it came up in a quantum information theory research problem that I am working on.  Mathematically, it's easy to define $\rho$ with infinite photon number variance: let $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ where $|\psi\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n|n\rangle$ such that $|a_n|^2=(n+1)^{-3}/\zeta(3)$ with $\zeta(3)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty1/k^3$ being the [Reimann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).  That is, $|\psi\rangle$ is a superposition of number states which is prepared such that the photon number of the state is distributed according to the [Zipf distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution).

However, I am wondering if such state (or one like it) can actually exist in nature.  If yes, how would one construct it?  If not, is there a concrete reason as to why? (ideally, I am looking for a mathematical proof, but would accept a generally accepted well-cited explanation.)

I am confused because it seems to me that the requirement if one applies a measurement $\sum_{m=k}^\infty|m\rangle\langle m|$ with a large $k$ to a coherent state there is a chance of it returning a positive answer, however small, as coherent states are not "peak photon number" limited (if they were, that chance would be zero starting at some fixed $k$).  Here the difference is the heavy tail on the photon number.

This is my first question to this forum.  I am not a physicist, I study information theory and have been looking at quantum information theory lately.  I know a lot of math, but not necessarily how things work in the "universe we touch".  I only have a rudimentary knowledge of quantum mechanics.  Please forgive my ignorance and feel free to refer this question somewhere else if it's not suitable for this forum.